# How do I loop over data in twig with knockout styled with bootstrap?

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap, knockout-2.0

This must be unique :p

I'm using twig in symfony2. I'm styling it with bootstrap fluid layout. Behold, I'm looping over data with knockout, with 4 (span3) in a row (every 5th one will wrap). But I don't know how to identify every 4th iteration.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="structureWhite clearfix" data-bind="foreach: stores">
        <div class="span3">
            <h5 data-bind="text: name"></h5>
            <p data-bind="text: address"></p>
            <p data-bind="text: contact"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I either need to put `<div class="row-fluid"></div>` after every 4th iteration or remove every 5th margin. The problem is that bootstrap doesn't give the first span3 margins, but all the rest get margin-left: 2.12766%. Which means with the 5th span3 (first one on the second row) is out of line.

So either I must split it up into fluid-row or remove the padding at the 5th element (or after every 4th) or add (although it'll be responsive so variable) margin to the first one. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

KO 2.1 now includes a `$index` context variable that you can access in your `foreach` to get the index of the current item.

It is an observable so if you are using it in an expression you need to use it like:

```
<!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 3 -->
<div>some element</div>
<! /ko -->
```

Comment: Nope, I get _Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko if_  - your example works, but remember I need to close the first row and open the second one, so my html is `</div><div class="row-fluid">`. Now what? Bit strange that ko will not work with unclosed tag :(

Comment: Sorry- missed this response.  It is not going to work to break the tags like that.  Your best bet is to map your view model to be in a structure that is more suitable for binding against.  Here is a sample that shows using a computed observable to build a 2D array (rows/columns).  In this sample, you can adjust the # of columns and it will recalculate the computed observable: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/82SQb/3/